# Why is my game object going up when "jump" button is only pressed once (when gravity in rigidbody is turned off) in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics, game-development

So I was trying to add jump button to my player in Unity and I was successful with it
But while test running the game, everything was fine until I switched off the gravity
I pressed the jump button once, and the player kept going up at const speed. I solved the problem by turning on the gravity again.

I just wanna know why did that happen?

This is my part of the "jump code" for reference:-

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(0,3,0); //rb : rigidbody object
            print("Jumped");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing can pull your rigidbody down if there is no gravity. Simple physics.

Comment: Newton Law : A body in motion stays in motion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ya canna change the laws of physics

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.